# Trouble with codeblocks installation on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, codeblocks

I installed Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 9.10, but when I start it from terminal, it shows the following error:
relocation error: /usr/lib/libcodeblocks.so.0: symbol _Z18wxSafeConvertWX2MBPKw, version WXU_2.8.2 not defined in file libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0 with link time reference
What is wrong with it? It seems to me I have installed all necessary libraries. Any ideas?
P.S. I am a Linux noobie - so sorry if it is some kind of a well-known mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that `libcodeblocks.so.0` was (apparently) linked against `libwx_baseu-2.8.2.so`, but the `libwx_baseu` you have installed is an earlier version 2.8.0.

Try locating `libwx_baseu-2.8.2.so` or some such and installing that.